# Как получить из json объекта последние значения?

Tags: php, яндекс-директ

Работаю с Yandex Direct Api. Методом `GetWordstatReportList` получаю результирующий ответ в виде json объект. Собственно он:

```
{"data": [
      {"ReportID": (int),"StatusReport": (string)}
      {"ReportID": (int),"StatusReport": (string)}
      {"ReportID": (int), "StatusReport": (string)}
   ]
}
```

Мне нужно получить средствами PHP последние значения. Необходимо знать последние значения "ReportID" и "StatusReport". Как это можно правильно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для обработки json в php используйте метод json_decode: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Далее обрабатываете полученный массив стандартными средствами.
Например:

```
$data = '{"data": [
    {"ReportID":1,"StatusReport":"aaa"},
    {"ReportID":2,"StatusReport":"bbb"},
    {"ReportID":3,"StatusReport":"ccc"}
]}';

$result = json_decode($data,true);

$last_element = end($result['data']);
//array(2) { ["ReportID"]=> int(3) ["StatusReport"]=> string(3) "ccc" }
$last_report_id = $last_element["ReportID"]; //3
$last_status_report = $last_element["StatusReport"];//ccc
```